# on single node kubernetes cluster i can expose a service with 'expose' cmd, but doing it via create -f <svc.json-file> fails

Tags: kubernetes

I am setting up a single node k8s cluster for testing, and we've run into a confusing problem with services.  I've distilled the example down to one of deploying a word press service, which i can do with  *kubectl create -f wordpress-rc.json* followed by an expose.     But when i follow the create of the rep controller by *kubectl create -f*  it fails.  i show all the json file content below.

rep controller:

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "wordpress",
    "labels": {
      "app": "wordpress"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "app": "wordpress"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "wordpress"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "wordpress",
            "image": "tutum/wordpress",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "name": "http-server",
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
           }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

service:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "wordpress",
    "labels": {
      "name": "wordpress"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
        "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "ports": [
      {
        "name":"wordpress1",
        "protocol":"TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "name": "wordpress"
    }
  }
}
```

***Working Command Sequence***

```
 alias kk kubectl
 kk create -f /tmp/wp-rc.json
 kubectl expose rc wordpress --type=LoadBalancer
```

***Failed Command Sequence***

```
  alias kk kubectl
  kk create -f /tmp/wp-rc.json
  kk create -f /tmp/wp-service.json
```

My question is why wouldn't the service definition work, while the expose command does ?

For completeness.. here is how i start up my single node k8s cluster. This is all running on centos 7, b.t.w:

```
#   magic selinux context set command is required. for details, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777111/cannot-create-a-shared-volume-mount-via-emptydir-on-single-node-kubernetes-on
#
sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/lib/kubelet


docker run --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data


docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 \
    /hyperkube kubelet --containerized --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" --address="0.0.0.0" --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests

docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2

sleep 20   # give everything time to launch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service json file used label selector `name: wordpress`, which is different from replication controller's label selector `app: wordpress`. This means the service created with that json file was targeting pods with `name: wordpress` label, but the replication controller was targeting pod with `app: wordpress` label. This is why your service created with json file didn't work as expected.

You may use `kubectl get svc wordpress -o yaml` to compare both created services.

Also, according to [config best practice](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/config-best-practices.html), it's recommended to create a service first, and then the replication controller:

> Create a service before corresponding replication controllers so that the scheduler can spread the pods comprising the service. You can also create the replication controller without specifying replicas, create the service, then scale up the replication controller, which may work better in an example using progressive disclosure and may have benefits in real scenarios also, such as ensuring one replica works before creating lots of them)

Comment: uh oh.  cock pit error !    thanks for spotting this.