# does fabric8 and kubernetes 1.2.4 not support watches on replication controllers ? (code that worked in 1.1 no longer works)

Tags: kubernetes, watch, fabric8

We are trying to upgrade from k8s 1.1 to 1.2.4 and the code that we have for creating watches on replication controllers
seems to no longer work: the watches  get created but we received no 'Added' or 'Modified' events for them.

I have created the smallest reproducible case I can and am   including it below.  For the convenience of 
anyone interesting in looking at this I am also including scripts to startup K8s 1.1  and k8s 1.2.4.

Please note the following about the test case:

```
0.  We use fabric8 1.3.91 to connect to k8s 1.2.4 and  fabric8 1.2.2 to connect to k8s 1.1.
1.  There are slight changes in the fabric8 API that will require you to 
    tweak the REPRODUCIBLE TEST CASE accoding to the version you run on.

        Please run the k8s 1.1 scenario first.  
        As-shipped, the test program will compile against that version.
        After that, please tweak as follows:

        comment out the following for new fabric8 
            import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.ConfigBuilder   

        replace masterUrl with: withMasterUrl

        comment out the onClose method of new Watcher { ... }


2.  you should start the appropriate the appropriate single node k8s script before you run the test program.

3.  make sure you create the namespace 'junk6', which you can do by saving 
    the lines below in a file ns.yaml, then typing    kubectl create -f ns.yaml

            kind: Namespace
            apiVersion: v1
            metadata:
              name: junk6
              labels:
                name: junk6

4.  For k8s 1.1 you will see a log message containing the string REPCONTROLLER, and the message
    future is done...     You will not see these when you run under k8s 1.2.4 because it seems 
    the watch message is never received.

5.  The name of the rep controller is spark master, but the image is redis. Please ignore that.
```

REPRODUCIBLE TEST CASE

```
package com.foo.blah

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ReplicationController
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.ConfigBuilder

//import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.ConfigBuilder   /* comment this out for new fabric8 */
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Watcher.Action
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client._

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.Try

//  To run:
//          make sure you have a namespace called  junk5   !

object BugReport extends App with StrictLogging {

  class RepControllerAndWatchCreator(val rc: io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ReplicationController,
                                     namespace: String) {

    def instantiate(kube: KubernetesClient, name: String): Future[Unit] = {
      {
        val promise = Promise[Unit]()
        logger.debug(s"setting up  'create complete' watch for component $name ")
        kube.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace).create(rc) /*  create the rc ! */
        val rcWatcher = getRcWatch(name, namespace,  promise)
        val rcWatch = kube.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace).withName(name).watch(rcWatcher)
        logger.debug(s"after rc watch - name $name")
        promise.future
      }
    }

    private[this] def getRcWatch(name: String,
                                 nameSpace: String,
                                 promise: Promise[Unit]): Watcher[ReplicationController] = {
      logger.debug(s"setting up  'create complete' watch for component $name ns=$namespace")

      new Watcher[ReplicationController]() {
        def eventReceived(action: Action, watchedRc: ReplicationController) {
          logger.debug(s"event recv'd for REPCONTROLLER  $name. action=$action [ $watchedRc ] ")
          promise.success()
        }
        /*      Uncomment this for newer version of fabric8 API.

        override def onClose(cause: KubernetesClientException): Unit = {
          if (!promise.isCompleted) {
            logger.trace("Watcher is close but promise is not completed.")
          }
        }

         */
      }
    }

    private[this] def isRcComplete(rc: ReplicationController) = {
      val retval = rc.getSpec.getReplicas == rc.getStatus.getReplicas
      logger.debug(s"isRcComplete [ ${rc.getMetadata.getName} ] = $retval")
      retval
    }
  }


  val k8sUrl = "http://localhost:8080"
  val namespaceName = "junk6"

  def go(): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val kube: KubernetesClient = getConnection
    val rc: ReplicationController = getRc

    val result: Future[Unit] = new RepControllerAndWatchCreator(rc, namespaceName). instantiate(kube ,"spark-master-rc")
    result onComplete  { (fut: Try[Unit]) =>
      println(s"future is done: $fut")
    }

    Thread.sleep(500 * 1000)
  }

  def getRc: ReplicationController = {
    val jsonTemplate =
      """
    |{
    |  "kind": "ReplicationController",
    |  "apiVersion": "v1",
    |  "metadata": {
    |    "name": "spark-master-rc",
    |    "labels": {
    |      "name": "spark-master"
    |    }
    |  },
    |  "spec": {
    |    "replicas": 1,
    |    "selector": {
    |      "name": "spark-master"
    |    },
    |    "template": {
    |      "metadata": {
    |        "labels": {
    |          "name": "spark-master"
    |        }
    |      },
    |      "spec": {
    |        "containers": [
    |          {
    |            "name": "spark-master",
    |            "image": "redis",
    |            "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
    |            "ports": [
    |              {
    |                "containerPort": 7077
    |              },
    |              {
    |                "containerPort": 8080
    |              }
    |            ],
    |            "resources": {
    |              "resources": {
    |                "cpu": "2000m",
    |                "memory": "4Gi"
    |              },
    |              "limits": {
    |                "cpu": "2000m",
    |                "memory": "4Gi"
    |              }
    |            }
    |          }
    |        ]
    |      }
    |    }
    |  }
    |}
      """.
    stripMargin
    System.out.println("json:" + jsonTemplate);
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonTemplate, classOf[ReplicationController])
  }

  def getConnection = {
    //val configBuilder =   new ConfigBuilder()       /*   For newer fabric8, replace with:  Config.builder() */
    val configBuilder =   new ConfigBuilder()       /*   For newer fabric8, replace with:  Config.builder() */
    val config =
      configBuilder.
        //masterUrl(k8sUrl).                    /* For newer fabric8, replace with:  withMasterUrl  */
        //withMasterUrl(k8sUrl).                    /* For older fabric8, replace with:  masterUrl  */
        masterUrl(k8sUrl).                    /* For newer fabric8, replace with:  withMasterUrl  */
        build()
    new DefaultKubernetesClient(config)
  }


  go()
}
```

STARTUP SCRIPT FOR K8s 1.1

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#   magic selinux context set command is required. for details, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777111/cannot-create-a-shared-volume-mount-via-emptydir-on-single-node-kubernetes-on
#
sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/lib/kubelet


docker run --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data


docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --vol
```

STARTUP SCRIPT FOR K8s 1.2.4

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#   magic selinux context set command is required. for details, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777111/cannot-create-a-shared-volume-mount-via-emptydir-on-single-node-kubernetes-on
#
sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/lib/kubelet

#docker run --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data

# Update k8s local cluster to latest stable version according to "Running Kubernetes Locally via Docker" 
# http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/
# export K8S_VERSION=$(curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)
export K8S_VERSION=v1.2.4
export ARCH=amd64

docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-${ARCH}:${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
    --containerized \
    --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
    --address="0.0.0.0" \
    --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
    --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
    --allow-privileged --v=2

#docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2

sleep 5   # give everything time to launch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer, from my colleague Vijay is expressed in the verification program below.

The key issue (also mentioned in [this bug report](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/432) to fabric8 folks) is that order of creation of object and watch on the object matters.
Thanks, Vijay !

To summarize the bug report:

if you switched the order of these statements

```
client.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("l", "v").watch(watcher);
createRc(client, namespace, podName, image);
```

to this:

````
createRc(client, namespace, podName, image);
client.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("l", "v").watch(watcher);

```
````

the program would cease to work.      Switching the order would have been fine in 1.2.2 as far as i can tell from the testing i have done.

** **Vijays Solution** **

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Quantity;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ReplicationController;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Watcher.Action;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Vijay {


  public static DefaultKubernetesClient getConnection ()  {
    ConfigBuilder
         configBuilder =   Config.builder() ;
    Config config =
      configBuilder.
        withMasterUrl("http://localhost:8080").
        build();
    return new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultKubernetesClient client = getConnection();

    String namespace = "junk6";
    String podName = "prom";
    String image = "nginx";

    Watcher<ReplicationController> watcher = new Watcher<ReplicationController>() {

      @Override
      public void onClose(KubernetesClientException cause) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void eventReceived(Action action, ReplicationController resource) {
        System.out.println(action + ":" + resource);

      }
    };


    client.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("l", "v").watch(watcher);

    createRc(client, namespace, podName, image);

  }

  private static void createRc(DefaultKubernetesClient client, String namespace, String podName, String image) {
    try {
      Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<String, String>();
      labels.put("l", "v");
      ReplicationController rc = client.replicationControllers().inNamespace(namespace)
          .createNew()
          .withNewMetadata()
          .withName(podName)
          .addToLabels(labels)
          .endMetadata()
          .withNewSpec()
          .withReplicas(1)
          .withSelector(labels)
          .withNewTemplate()
          .withNewMetadata()
          .addToLabels(labels)
          .endMetadata()
          .withNewSpec()
          .addNewContainer()
          .withName(podName)
          .withImage(image)
          .withImagePullPolicy("Always")
          .withNewResources()
          .addToLimits("cpu", new Quantity("100m"))
          .addToLimits("memory", new Quantity("100Mi"))
          .endResources()
          .endContainer()
          .endSpec()
          .endTemplate()
          .endSpec()
          .done();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This should be fixed now